# VLAN vs Subnet in switch

Tags: switch, vlan, subnet, switching, layer3

For VLAN communication we need a layer 3 device. For internetwork communication, we also need a layer 3 device. Then why did concept of VLAN emerge?

Comment: VLANs (mostly) separate a layer 2 network into several virtual layer 2 networks (hence the name ***Virtual LANs***). Then you need to use a layer 3 device if you want several layer 2 networks to talk to each other. What is the problem here?

Comment: The question is why vlan even emerged if we can use subnetting for segregating the environment.

Comment: You mean multiple subnets on one layer 2 network?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

A VLAN (Virtual LAN) is an implementation of a layer-2 broadcast domain. Originally, bridges, including switches, had all the interfaces in the same LAN, and broadcasts would be sent to all interfaces (except the originating interface). VLANs were created in order to be able to segment different bridge interfaces into different LANs, breaking up the network into multiple broadcast domains. This reduces broadcast traffic on each LAN. It also provides the ability to easily place restrictions (security) on traffic allowed between the VLANs.

On a layer-2 LAN, frames are delivered directly from one host to another host. In order for traffic from one layer-2 LAN to reach another layer-2 LAN, you need a layer-3 device, e.g. a router. Routers route packets between networks (LANs). Routers strip off the frames from the packets, and this means that you cannot broadcast between LANs.

On a layer-3 network, you also need a router to get to a different layer-3 network. Trying to run multiple layer-3 networks on the same LAN is problematic because routers should run split horizon, meaning a router will not route from an interface back out to the same interface. With VLANs, you can set up logical router interfaces on the same physical router interface to get around this.

There are some corner cases where you may want multiple layer-3 networks on the same LAN, but you really need to understand what you are doing before attempting this, and you should not expect hosts in one network to be able to communicate with hosts on a different network on the same LAN. This is why you will almost always see each layer-2 LAN (VLAN) with a different layer-3 network.